# session state in umbraco cms?

Tags: session, content-management-system, umbraco

I am currently working with the umbraco cms. I notice in the web.config references to session state.

My site will be on a web farm without a state server. Is umbraco reliant on session state? And if so, is it needed for content authoring or is it needed for content serving?

Answer (score 0):

The front end doesn't use any session variables at all unless you code it to do so, so that should be OK for the content serving side of things.

I'm not 100% on the back office, but I THINK it's all done with cookies, rather than sessions. The easiest way to check would be to disable sessions in the web.config file and try and use the back office. If it works, you're OK, otherwise it does need the session to work for content editing.